# Hi I want to write a piece of code to disable drag event of notification bar in android app

Tags: android

Hi I want to write a piece of code to disable drag event of notification bar in android app.

can some body help in this.

Comment: `I want to write a piece of code ...` Go, do it!

Comment: This is not possible, unless you have root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i am able to understand what u mean i guess this should help:

```
@Override
public void setDrawerState(boolean isEnabled) {       
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();       
}
```